# Notepad++ comment every opened file

Tags: notepad++

Using Notepad++, how would I add a /* to the beginning of the first line of every opened file, using the replace tool?

My failed attempt:

Find what: /^(.*)$/m

Replace with: /*$1

This results with 0 hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `^.*$`
Replace with: `/*$0`

Check <kbd>Regular expresion</kbd> and <kbd>Dot matches newline</kbd>